# Fell from great heights

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was having lunch with some German and American friends discussing about the state of an industry, when one of my friends said:

> ...... Industry has **fell from great heights**.

My German friends found it difficult to understand that phrase and unsure how to explain the meaning to them. How should I explain that phrase to them (in English)?

Comment: it simply means the industry **used to be very successful**, and it **used to have a lot of prestige**, and possibly it **used to have a lot of political clout** and, say, was **well-regarded by the public** -- however now it is not successful, has low prestige, perhaps has lost the political clout, and is poorly regarded by the public.

Comment: The basic forms are fall/fell/fallen. Shouldn't it be has fallen from great heights?

Comment: @rogermue Both seem to work (or at least sound like they do).

Comment: @JoeBlow Why do you post that as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev - Maybe some people say "has fell", but it is not standard English and sounds rather uneducated.

Comment: NOTE -- it should definitely be FALLEN in the sentence as seen.

Comment: The term "fallen from grace" may be more familiar in translation, and has roughly the same meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Since it is a direct quote, I cannot change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE - just TBC "fell" **is wrong**, it should read: "Industry has **fallen** from great heights."

---

"To fall from great heights" is an **idiom**

It simply means the industry used to be very successful, and it used to have a lot of prestige, and possibly it used to have a lot of political clout and, say, was well-regarded by the public.  However now it is not successful, has low prestige, perhaps has lost the political clout, and is poorly regarded by the public.

It's a common idiom, you can easily find in references.

---

NOTE - as Josh notes, the whole usage is rather clumsy.  Normally you'd use this idiom regarding (say) one movie star or politician.

Comment: I would say it's more of a metaphor.

Comment: a common idiom or metaphor used in an  uncommon context. I can understand the perplexity of his German friend.

Comment: Hmm - you know, IMO, it's fairly common to use "large broad categories" with that phrase.  For example "after WW2, politicians really fell from great heights -- they became like car dealers".  I feel it's fairly OKish usage - sure, a bit overblown.  You could easily say in Germany "the mittelstanding has fallen from great heights", say.  (I sure hope that is not actually the case! heh).  mfg

Answer (score 0):

[To collapse](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/collapse) is often used in economics to describe big fall in production, prices, performance etc.

> - to fall or decline suddenly, as in value

The Free Dictionary

- ...(Oil, Steel, Tech) Industry has collapsed.